# How should you handle snackbars when you have several messages popping up?

Tags: material

How should you handle snackbars when you have several messages popping up? Material says that you shouldn't stack them up, so should you put them in a queue and show them one at a time, or something else?

Comment: What is the context? What are the messages?

Answer (score 1):

Material Design tells us the following:

**Appearing and disappearing**

Snackbars appear without warning and don't require user interaction. They automatically disappear from the screen after a minimum of four seconds, and a maximum of...

**Consecutive snackbars**

When multiple snackbar updates are necessary, they should appear one at a time.

If you are using native material design, it is best to follow their rules and guidelines.
If you want custom components then you set the rules and interactions.
For example, you can set the maximum number of snackbars that appear on the screen, whether they hide after a certain one or are shown in a full list, etc.

Here are some links that might help you:

https://m2.material.io/components/snackbars#behavior

https://v3.mui.com/demos/snackbars/